# Regex. Remove <tr>, all its contents till ending tr tag

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a small matter if we were doing jQuery, just tag the TR and remove it etc.. But i am curious how one would do this in a strickly regex way.. which manipulating the dom.

I have this:

```
<tr id="anyName">
    <td>
         // a bunch of html
    </td>
</tr>
```

How would you use regular expressesions to replace that tr and everything in it to "".

I had this:

sometable.replace(".*?"," ");

I tried a few other things, but I cannot get this to work. Basically, I want the tr gone and all its contents. I am using a server side templating engine that processes all this data prior to coming into the view. So, I can hold this data as a string into this templating logic... and just remove it.. but since its a string, I need the regex to remove it.

Any ideas? I feel I am missing something very simple here.

Comment: You can use regular expressions on HTML only if the structure is tightly controlled (no recursive tags, etc). Your question does not specify how strict the structure is. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/39068 for a general case.

Comment: "I have a screw to screw in, but I am curious as to who one would do this using a hammer instead of a screw driver." Unless you can guarantee the HTML follows a very strict pattern, you're asking to write an HTML parser as a regular expression pattern. While it's possible to make a regex-based parser, it's not really possible to parse HTML using a regex. Either way, writing a parser is far beyond the scope of an SO answer.

Comment: It should be simpler to omit the not–required markup in the first place, or give it a class that sets it to *display: none*.

Comment: @ikegami If you bring the hammer down really gently with lots of freuent short taps, and hit the screw straight on, the threads will drive the screw in.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: I'm sure that's what the OP was thinking too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that `<tr>` can have nested `<tr>` tags inside..

And in some cases the `<tr>` tag **doesn't** have an **ending tag**(except XHTML)

So,regex won't be able to remove such tags even if you use odd numbered  pattern in regex

So, please **Don't** use regex for this

---

Since you are using jquery you can use [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
$('tr').remove();
```

or you can use some other server side html parser..But don't use regex..It could break your website

---

To answer your problem you could use this regex

```
 (?s)<tr[^<>]*>(.(?!<tr[^<>]*>))*?</tr>
```

or in javascript

```
 /<tr[^<>]*>(.(?!<tr[^<>]*>))*?<\/tr>/s
```

[demo](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gs&regex=%3Ctr%5B%5E%3C%3E%5D%2a%3E%28.%28?!%3Ctr%5B%5E%3C%3E%5D%2a%3E%29%29%2a?%3C/tr%3E&input=%3Ctable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cthead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3Enaam%3C/th%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3E...%3C/th%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/tr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C/thead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctbody%20id=%22results%22%3E%0A%0A%3Ctr%3E%0A%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E...%3C/td%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E...%3C/td%3E%0A%3C/tr%3E%0A%3C/tr%3E%0A%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E...%3C/td%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E...%3C/td%3E%0A%3C/tr%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3C/tbody%3E%0A%3C/table%3E)

But wait.you need to replace it continuously until it replaces all the content

So,you need to use **for loop** and loop until it replaces all ..

But this regex could break incase there's no closing  tag

Comment: +1 Not suggesting to use a regular expression, but… while the closing tag is optional, a regular expression could match everything up to, but not including, the next opening TR. Not sufficient for nested tables though. :-( Use a parser.

Answer (score 0):

@Anirudh is correct; this can be a very difficult problem, thanks to nested `<tr>` tags and unclosed `<tr>` tags.  But assuming you don't have nested or unclosed `<tr>` tags, you can indeed use regular expressions to solve this problem.

```
// if your html is in a variable called "html", you can get rid of <tr> tags thusly:
html = html.replace( /<tr[^]*?<\/tr>/, '' );
```

Note that we can't use `.*` in between the opening and closing `<tr>` tag.  Why?  Because the `.` wildcard does not match newlines, hence the "match anything" group of `[^]`.  Note also that we do not attempt to match the closing angle bracket in the opening `<tr>` tag, because there could be attributes in the tag.

If your HTML is well-formed, there *can't* be anything (other than comments) between your `<tr>` tags.  However, you have to take care if you do want to preserve those comments (and it's a good thing to get in the habit of thinking about in general): if you use the default greedy `*` quantifier, it'll gobble up everything from the first opening `<tr>` tag to the last closing one, including comments and any invalid code in between `<tr>` tags.  To fix this problem, make the quantifier lazy by appending a `?`.

See my solution (in JavaScript, *without* jQuery) here:

http://jsfiddle.net/TpeEj/2/